# Dynamically renew calculator input result

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have some calculator based on select option, 2 inputs. You dynamically get result when you change range or input data in text field. I needed to add some div "buttons" with fixed sizes. It works great when you choose select option and then feel inputs.
But when I choose select option then click on div (60x90 or 100x150) button, inputs get new values, but result doesn't renewed. Where is a problem? I think in $('#form').on('input change', 'select,input', function()

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(document).on('input', '#height', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
$(document).on('input', '#heightPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
});
$(document).on('input', '#width', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
});
$(document).on('input', '#widthPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#form').on('input change', 'select,input', function() {
        console.log(this.type)
        if(this.type == 'range') $(this).next().text(this.value) 
        var o = $(this).closest('.roword').find('select,input'),
            v = o.eq(0).val(),
            w = o.eq(1).val(),
            h = o.eq(3).val(),
            r = o.last().val('');
            if(v) { 
                v = v * w * h;
                r.val(v.toFixed())
            }
    })
});

function changeValue($this)
    {
        if($($this).text() == "60x90") {
        $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('60');
        $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('90');
  }
  if($($this).text() == "100x150") {
        $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('100');
        $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('150');
  }
    }
```

```css
.standart {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
<div class = "roword">
<div>
<select  name="type[]">
     <option value="">Choose type</option>
     <option value="1.1">Type1</option>
     <option value="1.4">Type2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-col-2">
     <input form="send" type="range"  min="40" max="200" id="height" name="height[]" value="40">
  <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="200" id="heightPlus" name="heightPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
</div>
<div class="form-col-3">
    <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="300" id="width" name="width[]" value="40"> 
  <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="300" id="widthPlus" name="widthPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 form-col-4">
     <input class="myPrice" form="send" type="text" name="result[]" readonly>
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">60x90</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">100x150</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `$('#form input:first').trigger('change');` at the end of your function, instead of adding `trigger` in each `if`, that would trigger and update the values:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', '#height', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#heightPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#width', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#widthPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form').on('input change', 'select,input', function() {
    console.log(this.type)
    if (this.type == 'range') $(this).next().text(this.value)
    var o = $(this).closest('.roword').find('select,input'),
      v = o.eq(0).val(),
      w = o.eq(1).val(),
      h = o.eq(3).val(),
      r = o.last().val('');
    if (v) {
      v = v * w * h;
      r.val(v.toFixed())
    }
  })
});

function changeValue(element) {
  if ($(element).text() == "60x90") {
    $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('60');
    $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('90');
  }
  if ($(element).text() == "100x150") {
    $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('100');
    $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('150');
  }
  $('#form input:first').trigger('change');
}
```

```css
.standart {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <div class="roword">
    <div>
      <select name="type[]">
     <option value="">Choose type</option>
     <option value="1.1">Type1</option>
     <option value="1.4">Type2</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col-2">
      <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="200" id="height" name="height[]" value="40">
      <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="200" id="heightPlus" name="heightPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
    </div>
    <div class="form-col-3">
      <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="300" id="width" name="width[]" value="40">
      <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="300" id="widthPlus" name="widthPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 form-col-4">
      <input class="myPrice" form="send" type="text" name="result[]" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">60x90</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">100x150</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `.trigger("change")` like below, then it will auto update the value

```
$('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('60').trigger("change");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', '#height', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#heightPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#width', function(event) {
    $(this).next().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#widthPlus', function(event) {
    $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#form').on('input change', 'select,input', function() {
    if (this.type == 'range') $(this).next().text(this.value)
    var o = $(this).closest('.roword').find('select,input'),
      v = o.eq(0).val(),
      w = o.eq(1).val(),
      h = o.eq(3).val(),
      r = o.last().val('');
    if (v) {
      v = v * w * h;
      r.val(v.toFixed())
    }
  })
});

function changeValue($this) {
  if ($($this).text() == "60x90") {
    $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('60');
    $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('90').trigger("change");
  }
  if ($($this).text() == "100x150") {
    $('input#heightPlus, input#height').val('100');
    $('input#widthPlus, input#width').val('150').trigger("change");
  }
}
```

```css
.standart {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <div class="roword">
    <div>
      <select name="type[]">
     <option value="">Choose type</option>
     <option value="1.1">Type1</option>
     <option value="1.4">Type2</option>
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-col-2">
      <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="200" id="height" name="height[]" value="40">
      <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="200" id="heightPlus" name="heightPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
    </div>
    <div class="form-col-3">
      <input form="send" type="range" min="40" max="300" id="width" name="width[]" value="40">
      <input form="send" type="text" maxlength="3" min="40" max="300" id="widthPlus" name="widthPlus[]" value="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 form-col-4">
      <input class="myPrice" form="send" type="text" name="result[]" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">60x90</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-5 post standart" onclick="changeValue(this)">100x150</div>
```